# Why does MATLAB give a "class has no property" error when running but not debugging?

Tags: matlab

I have a script that performs a bunch of experiments on different datasets, below is part of the logic to determine whether a dataset needs to be loaded. Basically we load the dataset if there is none already loaded, or if the currently loaded one doesn't match the one we need by name.

This example crashes with the error `The class dataset has no property or method named 'name'` at the `if` statement (the class does in fact have this property):

```
    if(~exist('dataset','var')||~strcmp(dataset.name,datasets{datai}.id))
        loaded=load(datasets{datai}.filename);
        dataset=loaded.dataset;
    end
```

If I debug and stop at the line, I can access dataset.name in the debugger without performing any further actions. I don't think the reason is the dataset object not existing. In the loop I ran, the first dataset was correctly loaded, but the second one (where the name check comes into play) wasn't.

This rewriting works:

```
    if(~exist('dataset','var')||~strcmp(nom,datasets{datai}.id))
        loaded=load(datasets{datai}.filename);
        dataset=loaded.dataset;
        nom=dataset.name;
    end
```

Why was I able to access `dataset.name` in the debugger, and why does the rewriting fix the issue?

Comment: Have you set the `GetAccess` attribute of `'name'` to `protected` or `private` ?

Comment: @articuno I didn't modify the default attributes of the properties. The doc says by default they're public. What's most confusing about this to me is that I can access the property in debugger, and I haven't been able to reproduce it with simpler classes.

Comment: can you show me `dataset`, i'll try to reproduce the issue.